# iPhone Music Library Access

Tags: iphone

I would like to develop an application for iPhone that classifies the user's music according to user-defined genres. The application should be able to have access to iPhone's Music Library and work on the files, this is, fetching an mp3 file, apply some DSP ( like MFCC coefficients ) and then save the results on the file itself.

Is it possible to obtain a song as a file and work on it?

Comment: This is now possible since iOS 4.0: http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/

Answer (score 5):

No. You have access to the music library database and can launch a music player to play a certain song but under the SDK you have neither access to the song files themselves nor to the actual PCM data of the music.

Also, access to the music library database on the device is strictly read-only, so you can't modify genres etc. if that was your plan.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but given that you can't access the music data from the iPhone, you might consider having a desktop app that accesses the user's music on their Mac/PC, and encodes something into the genre of the music there.  Then you could write a music player app for the iPhone that can understand your genre descriptor and function accordingly.  You could even go as far as having your iPhone app and desktop app communicate via WiFi to synch up data.